# Excel: ignoring 0 at start of numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of times which i want to add to a string

```
0900       1730
0900       1730
1000       1700
0930       1700
```

i need to break these up to hours and minutes like so

```
09  00       17  30
09  00       17  30
10  00       17  00
09  30       17  00
```

to do this i am using the MID() function to get the first two characters from the cell and then the last two. But when i do this for numbers that start with 0 of have 00 it drops the first 0 like so

```
0930 = ",MID(B2,1,2),",",MID(B2,3,2),"    output - 93  0      what i want = 09 30
0900 = ",MID(B2,1,2),",",MID(B2,3,2),"    output - 90  0      what i want = 09 00
1000 = ",MID(B2,1,2),",",MID(B2,3,2),"    output - 10  0      what i want = 10 00
```

is there a way to solve this?

Comment: change the format of the target cell to Personalized > `00`

Comment: do you mind explaining your longterm goal with this? there might be a better solution i.e., if you aiming at getting dateTimes out of these 0900 1730 things.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your edit. I would have thought the original version e.g. `output - 9 30 what i want = 09 30` would be what you require and not `output - 9 30 what i want = 93 0`

Comment: I think Jook may have a valid point. It may be better to convert the strings to time values first if you intend to use them for calcs. Something like `=TIMEVALUE(LEFT(D16,LEN(D16)-2) & ":"  & RIGHT(D16,2))` would work in this instance

Comment: @Alistair Weir: sorry i meant to edit the output field there and not what i want field! i changed it now.... no i do not want them to be output as 09:30, i need two separate numbers so i can add them to a database in two different columns(e.g. column1 = 09, column2 = 30)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mid of a pre-formatted block:

```
=MID(RIGHT("0000"&B2,4),1,2) =MID(RIGHT("0000"&B2,4),3,2)
```

This should give you two strings like `09` & `30`.
If you want two numeric values you can add a value function:

```
=VALUE(MID(RIGHT("0000"&B2,4),1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is place `Single Quote(')` before the 0 then it will store the 0930 as text in cell
and your formula will also work, No need to change in the formula.

```
So the value 0930 will be '0930
```

Comment: It will work also for `0900` until you are not converting it in a number

Comment: ya i just spotted that now... but the problem is that i have the cells formatted to have 4 numbers and if there is only 3 numbers in the cell to display a 0 at the end (e.g. 900 changes to 0900) but if you convert this cell to a string it drops the 0 at the start so you get '900

Comment: one possibility is to keep everything as numbers then only convert to a string when required using `=TEXT(A1,"0000")`